# Quick way to maxise power usage on the RPi Pico without external HW?

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking at powering a Pico over USB and I'd like to temporarily boost input current high, hopefully beyond 200 mA, certainly beyond 100 mA. What's a good way, programmatically, preferably from Python?

Set both cores to run at maximum clock? Have them both run FP32 calculations in a loop? Trigger all 4 ADCs to report input voltages? All of those at the same time? Something else?

Context/rationale: I'm trying to run the thing from a powerbank, which of course shuts off because the current used by the Pico is too low. What I'm considering doing is to have the Pico generate pulses of high current (e.g. 0.1s long) every 15-20s, just often enough to prevent the powerbank from shutting down. I'm looking for a SW solution because I want to do something with several units, so any other approach (custom HW load, UPSes etc.) seems to quickly complicate matters or make the system expensive or (why not?) both.

Comment: place a resistor across the power supply pins ... why should the Raspberry Pi do the current sinking?

Comment: @jsotola, thanks for the answer. I'm looking for a way to reset the powerbank's shutdown timer. A resistor represents a continuous load. If I can programmatically increase power drain on a Pico for a short period of time, just enough to reset the shutdown timer, that might be on the order of 50x more efficient, likely doubling overall runtime.

Comment: use a MOSFET to connect the resistor into the circuit periodically ... you could even use a standalone timer circuit

Comment: @jsotola, somethink like that might turn out to be a reasonable hardware hack if boosting power draw on the Pico itself proves to be impossible, yes. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Powerbanks are designed to **charge** phones.

Pico are designed to minimise power consumption.

If you want a stable supply use something more appropriate.

Pico have very flexible power needs and can operate directly from a Li-ion cell.

Comment: I understand Pico's flexibility, but then not everything I have connected to the Pico is as flexible. For example, a Li-ion cell's 3.7V is very likely too low for a peripheral I have connected to it and even if it wasn't, being able to use a powerbank would be a vastly superior solution in so many ways: much less messy, cost-effective, implement-once-and-run-on-any-number-of-devices-just-works, to name a few. And the numerous inquiries into this possibility suggest there is (unsurprising) wide demand for  it. It might turn out not to be possible, but I don't know that, yet.